# Changing TextView font in PyGTK

Tags: python, application-development, gtk, pygtk, glade

I have TextView widget in Glade named "formula-view". I'm trying to do this to change font:

```
formulaView = self.builder.get_object("formula-view")
fontdesc = pango.FontDescription('Ubuntu 16')
formulaView.override_font(fontdesc)
```

But this works with error. How to correctly change font?

I just want to change the font of a widget, but I don't know how to do it. Error looks like this: `AttributeError: type object 'Context' has no attribute '__info__'`

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I just want to change the font of a widget, but I don't know how to do it. Error looks like this: `AttributeError: type object 'Context' has no attribute '__info__'`

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this instead:

```
tv = self.builder.get_object('textview')
font = pango.FontDescription('Ubuntu 16')
tv.modify_font(font)
```

Comment: This also doesn't work